# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.:

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing facebook app Locally. After initializing the facebook SDK, I am trying to login to the Facebook. I am failing with the following error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.  
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  
It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

My web page is `file:///C:/Users/aanilkum/Desktop/work/Conductor/test_conductor/test_mini.html`

Comment: You should run it on a server to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it on a server to do it. A web server, that is locally hosted is the basic requirement. You can use any of these servers for it:

- **Windows**

  - [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
  - [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
- **Linux**

  - [LAMP](http://lamphowto.com/)
- **Mac OS**

  - [MAMP Server](http://www.mamp.info/en/)
  - [MAMP Server Pro](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried running server, but i am working in private network which has 192.168.1.100 ip. If i use this it is also resulting in the above error.